# Reading and outputting a file line by line - why is this solution failing?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, file-io

I know there are other methods for opening and reading a file line by line.
However, I was trying out other methods and thought the following would work:

```
with open('example.txt', 'r') as a_file:
    for x in enumerate(a_file):
        print(a_file.readlines()[x[0]])
```

This will however, only output the second line in the file. I thought that the x value in the `for` loop, if only using the first value in the tuple, would enable me to iterate through the lines printing them out one after the other.

What have I not understood?

Comment: Once you read the file you have to reset the descriptor. `readlines` reads the **entire** file and now you have nothing left to read in all following iterations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to this:

```
with open('example.txt', 'r') as a_file:
    for line in a_file:
        print(line)
```

Since the file object is already iterable.

In your case you are reading the entire file in each iteration (that is what `readlines` does). After the first iteration there is nothing left to read.

Comment: Of course. I feel silly now. Thank you for your time.